# How can I figure out the password from the information below. CTF problem

Tags: ctf

I'm trying to figure out the password that will allow me to obtain the flag from this CTF challenge website.

So far I've used the python requests library and the GET function to get these lines.

```
<div class="container">
  <form action="bad_code.php">
   <br/> password:
    <input type="text" name="passwd" class="input"/><br/>
  </form>
  </br>
</div>
```

I've tried inputting the input type, the name, and the class as the password, but they were all wrong. I'm not sure how to go from here to get the password. Can anyone help suggest here to go from here?